# Failed to retrieve the apex manifest resource for your organization - eclipse debugger for force.com

Tags: apex, force.com, eclipse, debugging

I have followed this document - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_overview.htm

So set up debugger using eclipse. When I click the debug icon (Debug icon) and launch the new debug configuration it does load few things and i get this error message.

**Failed to retrieve the apex manifest resource for your organization**

eclipse logs

!ENTRY com.salesforce.ide.core 2 0 2017-05-18 11:53:01.762

!MESSAGE  WARN [2017-05-18 11:53:01,760] (HTTPAdapter.java:unmarshallResponse:99) - No response from server for https://cs43.salesforce.com/services/datav38.0/tooling/apexManifest

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to provide my company proxy on eclipse for apex debugger to work.